# PHPDoc type hinting overlapping types

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc, jetbrains-ide, type-hinting

I have a class called `Resource` but with a fully qualified name like `com.example/objects/Resource`

If I write a file

```
use com.example/objects/Resource;

/**
 * Do something
 * 
 * @param Resource $r 
 */
function myfunc( Resource $r ) {
    $r->something();
}

$x = new Resource();
myfunc($x);
```

Then everything works fine. Because of my `use` statement, the PHP typehinting is able to handle the the fact that I've passed a variable of type `com.example/objects/Resource` even though myfunc is only comparing against `Resource`

The problem is that PHPStorm is not able to handle this. I'm unable to use autocomplete and I get a warning on `myfunc($x)` which says `Expected Resource, got Resource` and a warning within the function which says `Method 'something' not found in the class Resource`. Obviously PHPStorm is assuming I'm using the builtin `resource` class and not my own `Resource` class.

If I change the PHPDoc and the function definition to use the fully qualified name, then the previous warnings go away but I get a minor warning which says `Unnecessary fully qualified name.` I suppose one solution would be to use the fully qualified name and disable the minor warning, but I'd rather not have to use fully qualified names everywhere. I know it's my own fault for creating a class which has the same name as a built in type, but I'm wondering if there is anyway to make this work? Apart from renaming my `Resource` class?

Comment: Use alias. e.g. `use com.example/objects/Resource as MyResource;`

Comment: use "\" instead of "/"  in namespaces ^^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use an `alias` when importing the class. More information can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php). *Example:*

```
use com.example\objects\Resource as MyResource;

/**
 * Do something
 * 
 * @param MyResource $r 
 */
function myfunc( MyResource $r ) {
    $r->something();
}

$x = new MyResource();
myfunc($x);
```

You could also specify the whole namespace and class name instead of just the class name. *Example:*

```
/**
 * Do something
 * 
 * @param com.example\objects\Resource $r 
 */
function myfunc( com.example\objects\Resource $r ) {
    $r->something();
}

$x = new com.example\objects\Resource();
myfunc($x);
```

If you're in a namespace and using this approach, make sure to use a leading `\` on your full class name specifier (e.g. `$x = new \com.example\objects\Resource();`).